# I want to delete the all the file with the same extension

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, apache-http-server, filesystems

I have thousands of files with the below hierarchy.

Mail folder -> sub folder -> example.xlsx
Mail folder -> sub folder -> example.bck

for example, I have thousands of "Main Folder" and files as above hierarchy and want to delete all the files with extensions of .xlsx and .back.

I have an ubuntu server. Is there any way to do it quickly?

Comment: With such questions, it would be helpful if you would also explaiwhich shell you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find . -name "*.xlsx" -type f -delete
```

To be sure of deleting the right files, run first as check:

```
find . -name "*.xlsx" -type f
```

Ensure that `-delete` is the *last argument* in the command,
as when placed before `-name` it will delete *everything*.

Comment: Perhaps it should be `MailFolder` instead of `.`, because the OP wants to remove files below the mail folder and not below the working directory.